# Que sucede en una asignación de objetos de lista c#

Tags: c#

```
    public class ListaMetodosDuda
{
    //Primer lista que permaneceria intacta
    List<string> nombres1;

    //Segunda lista que pasa por algun filtro y se borra para asignarle nuevos valores
    List<string> nombres2;
    public ListaMetodosDuda()
    {
        nombres1 = new List<string>();
        nombres2 = new List<string>();
    }

    public void Adicionar(string nombre)
    {
        nombres1 = nombres2; 

        nombres1.Add(nombre);

        //borra ambas nombres1, nombres2 
        nombres1.Clear(); 
    }
}

ListaMetodosDuda lista = new ListaMetodosDuda();
    lista.Adicionar("Francisco");
    lista.Adicionar("Eduardo");
    lista.Adicionar("Martin");
    lista.Adicionar("AAceves");
    lista.Adicionar("Manuel");
```

*Buenas tardes comunidad necesito saber, del código anterior porque al realizar esta asignación*

```
nombres1 = nombres2;
```

*los objetos se comportan como si, se tratasen de uno mismo, ejemplo: cuando voy guardando en la lista  **nombres1**, los valores que voy guardando también se guardan en **nombres2**, de igual forma si hago el borrado de valores en nombres1, también se realiza en  nombres2, pensé **nombres1**, era totalmente independiente pero no es así, este comportamiento lo extraje de otros códigos que vi en internet.
Quisiera saber que sucede, que concepto de programación existe, cuando se realiza la asignación **nombres1 = nombres2;** que pareciera que ambos objetos quedan conectados, lo que sucede en uno se refleja en el otro.

Al pendiente de sus respuestas, por si necesitan mas información sobre mi duda*

Comment: Al hacer nombres1 = nombres2, las dos variables apuntan al mismo objeto. por lo tanto lo que hagas en una se vera reflejada en la otra. por lo bajo, las dos variables son punteros a esos objetos.

Comment: Investiga acerca de la diferencia entre [Value Type y Reference Type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types). Lost **tipos** `List<string>` que tienes como nombre1 y nombre2 son *Reference Type*, es decir, **tienen una referencia a la dirección de memoria** donde están los valores, **no el valor mismo**. Como dice gbianchi, cuando haces nombre2=nombre1, estás creando un objeto que **APUNTA** a la **misma dirección de memoria** que nombre1.

Comment: Muchas gracias, investigare sobre lo que me comentan. Se escucha interesante el tema